# p5.js a problem when using setInterval, array.push(), for loop to create animation

Tags: javascript, arrays, processing, setinterval, p5.js

Using `setInterval`, `array.push()`, for loops, I want one bubble to appear every **3 seconds** until the length of the array bubbles becomes **10**.

However, when I execute my code, 10 bubbles appear altogether at once, and `console.log(array.length)` shows that the length is growing, although I set it to be smaller than 10.
I think there is something wrong with how I arrange the codes, can anyone help?

```js
let bubbles = [];
var n = 10;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(600, 400);
}

function addBubbles() {
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        let x = random(50, 550);
        let y = random(50, 350);
        let r = random(10, 50);
        let b = new Bubble(x, y, r);
        setInterval(bubbles.push(b), 3000);
    }
}

function draw() {
    background(0);
    addBubbles();
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      bubbles[i].show();
      bubbles[i].move();
    }
}

class Bubble {
    constructor(_x, _y, _r, _c) {
        this.x = _x;
        this.y = _y;
        this.r = _r;
        this.c = _c;
    }

    move() {
        this.x = this.x + random(-5, 5);
        this.y = this.y + random(-5, 5);
    }

    show() {
        stroke(255);
        noFill();
        strokeWeight(4);
        ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.r * 2);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems in your code.

**Problem 1:**
Every time your canvas is drawn, you're starting 10 intervals. Each of these intervals will run a function every 3 seconds. This would quickly (and exponentially) give you a *lot* of bubbles.

To add 1 bubble every 3 seconds, you only need to start 1 interval. You can do this in your `setup` function as it's only called once.

You can add a check to the `addBubble` function that will cancel the interval once you have a certain number of bubbles.

**Problem 2:**
You're not passing a function as a parameter when calling `setInterval()`.

You've passed `bubbles.push(b)` as the function to run every 3 seconds. `bubbles.push(b)` doesn't return a function type.

Instead of passing the return value of `bubbles.push`, we'll pass a function that adds a bubble to your array.

**Problem 3:**
You're only iterating over `n` (10) of your bubbles when drawing the canvas. Instead, you need to iterate over all of them.

```
let bubbles = [];
let maxBubbles = 10;
let interval;

funtion setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 400);
  interval = setInterval(addBubble, 3000);
}

function addBubble() {
  let x = random(50, 550);
  let y = random(50, 350);
  let r = random(10, 50);
  let b = new Bubble(x, y, r);
  bubbles.push(b);

  if (bubbles.length >= maxBubbles) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(0);

  for (let bubble of bubbles) {
    bubble.show();
    bubble.move();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you have accurately implemented the setInterval() method and the result you are getting is quite fair based on the way you've organised your code, because your addBubbles() method is being executed before the FOR loop gets any chance to start, that's why you're getting the 10 bubbles at once.
I would suggest you to throw the addBubbles() method inside the loop like this:

```
 for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    addBubbles();
  }
```

In this way your addBubbles() method will get executed each 3000 milliseconds along with the incrementation.